# Need to override cascade style

Tags: css

i have a style :

```
.window .div {
    border:medium solid #000000;
    height:150px;
    background-color: #0099FF;
    }
```

and then i have another style:

```
 #NewDiv {
    font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 20px;
    border-bottom-width: medium;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #000000;
        }
```

I need to put a #NewDiv div tag inside of window .div, BUT... #NewDiv must retain its own styling while sitting inside of window .div div tags.  How do I do this?

Currently when I try, #NewDiv takes on the same styling as window .div when i place it inside of it and i dont want that at all. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<div class="window">
    <div>
        <div id="NewDiv">Whats Wrong Here?</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `window` HTML element and the `.div` class doesn't really make sense. What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Also, `font` is a shorthand, either declare the font as `font: 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;` or `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif`.

Comment: What does your HTML look like when you add `#NewDiv` in?

Comment: <div class="window">
    <div><div id="NewDiv">Whats Wrong Here?</div></div>
</div>

Comment: Then the problem is caused by a typo in your existing CSS. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `!important` suffix to override styles. Or even better, make the rule for `#NewDiv` more explicit, like:

```
window .div #NewDiv
```

Comment: Yep, that's why i recommended updating the selector.

Comment: None of these suggestions work.... does it matter if its .window .div?
I realize i left off the dot before.

Comment: @WillingLearner: I don't think so, `#id` is always more specific than `.class .class`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first selector is wrong because of the typo in `.div`. There are no `<div class="div">`s in your HTML. Therefore nothing is being given a height of `150px`. Since there is no height set, it looks as if `.window` and its contents are all the same height of `20px`.

**EDIT:** your current border styles don't specify anything for top, left and right. That means they're inheriting from `.window div` and are not set to zero.

Try replacing your styles with this:

```
.window div {
    border: medium solid #000000;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #0099FF;
}

#NewDiv {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 20px;
    /* Set the border width here. Style and color will be inherited from above */
    border-width: 0 0 medium 0;
}
```

Comment: I need the border-bottom for #NewDiv to act as an underline. Not really seeing much of a difference here from my original example. Ive tried this with no luck. I want to know how to override everything for nested divs generally speaking, in case i wish to make a design change later.

Comment: @WillingLearner: That means you want `#NewDiv` to have a bottom border only and no other borders?

Comment: @BlotClock: Yes, no other borders for this style right now at the moment, just border-bottom.

Comment: @WillingLearner: OK I got it, see if my edit solves your problem.

Comment: @WillingLearner: This is what it looks like on jsFidde: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/dcHaj

Comment: @boltClock: i dont know why its working on jsfiddle, but not in my file. Extremely weird.

Answer (score 0):

As BoltClock says, ".div" should be "div" in your CSS since you have not applied this as a class within your html.

Also, to override styles of parent containers, you need to respecify each of these. Below, I have redefined the border property of #NewDiv as none (to remove .window's border) and then specified border-bottom (to add the underline effect).

```
.window div {
    border:medium solid #000000;
    height:150px;
    background-color: #0099FF;
}

#NewDiv {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 20px;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:medium solid #000000;
}
```